# Forcing area graph's X-Axis tick marks based on data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am using D3's area chart to construct a chart for data with this structure:

```
data = [
  {
    date: "2019-02-01", 
    value: 100
  }, {
    date: "2019-03-01", 
    value: 1
  }
]
```

When I use [D3's Area Chart Example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/area-chart) they set the X-Axis like:

```
const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => Date.parse(d.date)))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0));
```

However, this adds tick marks evenly throughout the X-Axis. I attempted something like:

```
const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", 'translate(0,' + (height + data.length) + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(data.length).tickSizeOuter(0));
```

but then nothing appeared in the X-axis.. How can I get the X-axis to only display tick marks on the given `date` values from my data (i.e. for the example data above, I only want to see `2019-02-01` and `2019-03-01` on the X-axis).

Even better would to just display the Month and Year of those dates (i.e. `2019-02-01` would be displayed as `Feb. 2019` on the graph).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which values should be ticks by providing an array to  `axis.tickValues()` containing the desired tick values. If your ticks should be values in your data array, then you only need to loop through your array and pick out the values. In your case this might look like:

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(x)
  .tickValues(
     data.map(function(d) { return timeParse(d.date); })
  )
```

If your scale is is a time scale, then the values must be date objects, so we can't pass the formatted dates. But, if we want to specify how the tick will be displayed, then we can also pass a format to `axis.tickFormat`, this will let you set how the dates appear. Together we get:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = data = [
  {
    date: "2019-02-01", 
    value: 100
  },
  {
    date: "2019-03-1", 
    value: 50
  },
  {
    date: "2019-05-01", 
    value: 1
  }

];

var timeParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var timeFormat = d3.timeFormat("%B %Y");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data,function(d) { return timeParse(d.date); }))
  .range([20,300]);
  
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range([10,100]);
  
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(timeParse(d.date)); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", line);
  
// Axis:
var axisBottom = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(x)
  .tickValues(data.map(function(d) {
    return timeParse(d.date); // specify which values should be ticks.
  }))
  .tickFormat(timeFormat);
  
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(0,100)")
  .call(axisBottom);
  
  
  
svg.selectAll("text")
  .attr("text-anchor","start")
  .attr("transform","rotate(90)translate(10,-13)");
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="400"></svg>
```